# Errors while building `ghc` : `alex`, `happy` are missing / fatal error in GHC module, with version bounds in `process`

Tags: haskell, build, cabal

Today, I upgraded my repo to GHC 9.2.4. As part of it, cabal tried to build `hspec-2.9.7`, which requires `ghc` library. So, it builds `ghc-9.2.4`, and there was a problem.

First, it says:

```
Error: cabal-3.8.1.0: The program 'alex' is required but it could not be
found
```

so I did `cabal install alex` and retry.

Then, it says:

```
Error: cabal-3.8.1.0: The program 'happy' is required but it could not be
found
```

Something was fishy, but anyway I did `cabal install happy` and proceeded. Note that I never needed to install either alex or happy before when building `hspec`.

The next build gave off tons of errors like:

```
GHC/Builtin/Names.hs:2073:2: error:
     fatal error: primop-vector-uniques.hs-incl: No such file or directory
     2073 | 
          |  ^                              
     |
2073 | 
     |  ^
compilation terminated.

GHC/Builtin/PrimOps.hs:67:2: error:
     fatal error: primop-data-decl.hs-incl: No such file or directory
       67 | 
          |  ^                         
   |
67 | 
   |  ^
compilation terminated.
(...continues like this)
```

After hours of debug later, I found some clue: version bounds on `process` package (`process >= 1.6.14`) is causing the problem. Apparently, default `ghc` cannot be used with other versions of `process`.

Now I am wondering why

1. `ghc` package cannot be built manually
2. `ghc` package requires the specific version of boot libraries

Why is it so picky to deal with?

Comment: Tried hspec 2.10.6 as well, also did not work.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in either cabal or GHC. The `ghc` library should never be re-installed AFAIK. Please file a bug report.

Comment: @sjakobi Made an issue https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/8489 - It seems like bounds on `process` package is causing problem. Should I downgrade `process` package to match the one `ghc` was built with?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds worth trying.

Comment: Downgrading worked, but I feel bad. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Maybe  `hspec-core` can drop the `ghc` dependency, possibly by using `ghc-lib-parser` instead?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported in https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/8489 , resolved by associated PR - now it provides better error messages.

Basically, the crux of the problem is that `ghc` package is non-upgradable. It depends on `process` package, so you need specific `process` package version as well if you depend on `ghc`.